# Localizing name of a content type in Orchard

Tags: localization, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

How can I localize the name of an inbuilt content type, in this case "Page"?

I have localized other parts of the admin interface through using the relevant po files etc. so I'm reasonably familiar with that process.

When I couldn't find another way of doing it, I renamed the "Display name" of "Page" to what I want it to be called. Which works in this case as the site will only be run in the one language but it's obviously not the "right" way of doing it so would be interesting to know how to do it properly..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't currently localize content type, part and field display names. There are bugs open for this but they haven't been fixed yet.

Comment: Ok thanks, good to know. I'll stay with my workaround for now then.